# Creating an iPhone library/framework

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Are there any tutorials describing how to create a library or is it framework for the iPhone?  I have a number of methods that are shared between applications.  These will be better maintained as a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of information on the web that can help with this for example [this](http://www.mobileorchard.com/sharing-compiled-code-building-static-libraries-in-xcode-for-the-iphone/).

Comment: Try this link if this question becomes Google's top result: http://tinyurl.com/cwq4tn

Comment: If you want auto updates when the library source changes: http://tinyurl.com/cleuhw

Comment: The let me google that for you link is pretty dumb, as google is finding this page when you search for the topic.

Comment: That's why I added the second Google link.

Answer (score 3):

Put your code in a static library (as Roger indicated via his link). However, consider using an Xcode cross-project reference to "import" that static library into all the other projects that need it. I've whipped up a tutorial explaining how to do this (and why I think it's better than creating a "fat" Universal Binary): http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/

Comment: Thanks Clint, this is exactly what I've been looking for. Great job!

Answer (score 0):

A much more recent (and more powerful) way to do the "single library file that covers both simulator and devices":

[Build fat static library (device + simulator) using Xcode and SDK 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4)

(I wrote one of the posts referred to in the accepted answer; that was valid for Xcode3 at the time, but Apple deliberately broke it with later versions, and offered no alternative. So, we ended up with the SO question / answer above)