# Framework/Component for iOS

Tags: iphone, frameworks

I would like create a plug and play component.(i.e)I like to create a small component/Framework which can be used in many iPhone apps.For example GPS location tracking ,Chat functionalities like that.Each and everyone should be separate component which can be integrated with any apps.

Can anyone guide me with things to be done for achieve this.Any tutorials or links.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out below link

[help guide to create lib](http://mobileorchard.com/sharing-compiled-code-building-static-libraries-in-xcode-for-the-iphone/)

[question help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696051/creating-an-iphone-library-framework)

Regards,

Shyam Parmar

Answer (score 0):

This can also maybe help:
http://www.eosgarden.com/en/articles/xcode-static-libraries/